# ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Software caused connection abort

Tags: apache, mod-security2

I'm having a problem with Apache 2.4 with ModSecurity. Sometimes an error appears in the log for ModSecurity:

```
Apache-Error: [file "apache2_util.c"] [line 271] [level 3] [client <IP>] ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Software caused connection abort [hostname “<hostname>”]
```

The error as I saw it accompanied attempts to edit something on pages or actions on files via website. I'm trying increase SecRequestBodyLimit, SecResponseBodyLimit, SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit, SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit because I suspected just had too low values for these variables. I'm finally getting the values set close hard limit and the problem still exists. Maybe someone has an idea for this problem?

I use CentOS 7 with ius packages:
httpd24u-2.4.41-1
httpd24u-mod_security2-2.9.2

Answer (score -1):

I [recently updated that package to version 2.9.3](https://github.com/iusrepo/httpd24u-mod_security2/issues/4), you can update it from the testing repository and see if that resolves the issue for you.

```
yum --enablerepo ius-testing update httpd24u-mod_security2
```

If not, I'd recommend [reporting it upstream](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues).